# Heathrow Terminal 3 to Shenfield on Elizabeth Line

Tags: uk, trains

I want to go to Forest Gate from Heathrow Terminal 3 on the Elizabeth line, but can't get any such route on Google or Citymapper. But Elizabeth Line shows a route from Terminal 3/4/5 to Shenfield (via Forest Gate). I have a lot of luggage, so don't want to go through any interchange. All the routes shown on Google/Citymapper have an interchange in Paddington/Whitechapel.

[Elizabeth Line Routes](https://tfl.gov.uk/elizabeth-line/route/elizabeth/)

I got a Elizabeth Line route on TFL but am confused about the time listed!
[Timetable for April](https://content.tfl.gov.uk/elizabeth-line-december-2022.pdf)

Comment: When are you traveling? If you putting in that route for today you would not be able to take the Elizabeth Line straight through because there are engineering works on the central London part of the Elizabeth Line today. See https://tfl.gov.uk/tube-dlr-overground/status/#line-elizabeth . If you want to travel another date you should specify that

Comment: When are you planning to make this trip? Timetables will change on May 21. Until then there are no direct services from Heathrow to the Shenfield branch, you have to change trains somewhere on the central section, but it’s just a matter of getting off the train, staying on the platform, waiting for the right train, and getting back onto the train. Not sure which station would be best for this though.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I m sorry, forgot to mention the date, I will be coming on the 22nd of this month. I guess, I just have to wait on the same platform, not a big deal then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Elizabeth Line serves both Heathrow and Forest Gate, but trains follow different service patterns, and currently all Heathrow trains go down the Abbey Wood branch, and not the Shenfield branch.

Fortunately it’s very easy to change:

- Take the first Elizabeth Line train from Heathrow
- Get off at any station between Paddington and Whitechapel but stay on the **same platform**
- Wait around 3-5 minutes for the next Shenfield train
- Take this Shenfield-bound train to Forest Gate

From the 21st of May 2023 there will be some direct trains from Heathrow to Shenfield, but sometimes it will still be quicker to change.